# How to divide large data set into n subsets mantaining the class proportion

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am working in a binary classification problem and I'm using a large data set (the number of samples is large, the features not so much). The data is imbalance but I am using a weight array that fixes this issue (sort of).

I've been trying some classifiers with sklearn in a small version of this set, and apparently SVM works good for what i want. However, once I try to fit a SVM in the whole data set, it takes forever (and I also run out of memory).

What I want to know is if there's any fast way in Sklearn to divide this set, let's say in 10 subsets, maintaining the proportion of the classes, so can I then divide each of this subsets into training/testing and fit the SVM independently for each subset (so i could use different processors too)?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `new column` which will be a `random number` from 0 to 1 with `np.random.random_sample`, and then you can `group by` the `class` and apply `pd.cut` to the generated random number like creating a new column `dataset`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], 100), 
               'value': np.random.random_sample(100)})
df['dataset'] = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('class').apply(lambda x: 
pd.cut(x['value'], 10, labels=range(0, 10)))).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

Comment: I think you have forgotten to consider the imbalance existing in the label's distribution. You should not uniformly sample the data in that way. The better way is to separate positive and negatives, and sample in a way that for each set we have equal positive and negatives

Comment: No I didn't forget. The group by class takes care of keeping the class proportion in each dataset.

Comment: code too complex and description too vague

Answer (score 1):

`StratifiedKFold` function can serve your requirement. It will split the data into k number of stratified folds. call the `_iter_test_masks()` or `_make_test_folds()`,

Based on [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html):

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True)
>>> for i in skf._iter_test_masks(X, y):
...     print(i)

[ True False False  True]
[False  True  True False]

>>> for i in skf._make_test_folds(X, y):
...     print(i)

1
0
0
1
```

Comment: That is similar to what i am looking for. Can I just put 1 split with 5 folds so i can get my whole data set divided in 5 equal parts and then assign them to different df independenly?

Comment: In fact, `StratifiedKfold` does only one split. `.split()` gives a iterator for CV;  In each iteration, one fold is kept as test fold. Since you need to test fold alone, try my updated answer